# Why am I getting (lldb) Run time Error on Xcode for the following code?

Tags: c, arrays, file

I have written this code in an attempt to read a .txt file. I am getting the following outcome when trying to run it...

```
int main()
{
FILE *pToFile = fopen("Marks.txt", "r");

int line = 0;
int num;

char Students[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100 && ( fscanf(pToFile, "%d" , &num) == 1); ++i)
{
    Students[line] = num;
    printf("%d", Students[line]);
}

fclose(pToFile);
}
```

I am unsure how to solve this issue. Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Please post the code in the question itself, not the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that `Marks.txt` is not located in the directory where the executable generated by the IDE wants to load it. Consequently, `pToFile` will get `NULL` and the subsequent `fscanf` will fail.

Always test the result of `fopen`, e.g. like

```
FILE *pToFile = fopen("Marks.txt", "r");
if (!pToFile) {
   printf("failed to open file.");
   return 1;
}
...
```

And place `Marks.txt` in the directory where XCode generated the executable. You get this easily in XCode by right-clicking - under the Products-Tree - on your product and choose "Show in Finder":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
Students[line] = num;
```

`Line` doesn't change i.e it always `0`, so either increment it or use loop variable. For e.g

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100 && ( fscanf(pToFile, "%d", &num) == 1); ++i) {
        Students[i] = num
        printf("%d ", Students[i]); 
}
```

And always check the return value of `fopen()` to knwo whether call to `fopen()` was success or not. For e.g

```
File *pToFile = fopen("Marks.txt","r");
if(pToFile == NULL) {
   /* @TODO error handling */
   return 0;
}
```